# Is there an &nbsp; that WILL allow me to line wrap?

Tags: html, htmlspecialchars

I'm doing a simple string replacement of space ("") with `&nbsp;` to get some rudimentary formatting (multiple spaces in a row). However I finally discovered after all these years that `&nbsp;` actually stands for non-breaking space, and I don't get any line wraps if I do a blanket replacement on my entire string.

Is there a special html character for a space that *will* break? The other replacement is to simply to my replacement search for double-spaces only.

Comment: Can't you use margin/padding instead of spaces?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I dont if that exist,  have you tried looking in this [site](http://www.robinlionheart.com/stds/html4/spchars) ? maybe you could find some alternative.

Comment: that or something markdown-like is ideal, yes. Just doing some rudimentary prototyping and asking more for curiosity since I didn't know that aspect about nbsp before.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `&nbsp;` followed by `&#8203;` to make breakpoints. It's zero-width space character that is used for making breakspaces inside words at specific points

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a</div>
<div>a&nbsp;&#8203;&nbsp;&#8203;&nbsp;&#8203;&nbsp;&#8203;&nbsp;&#8203;&nbsp;&#8203;&nbsp;&#8203;a</div>
```